# Accessing VR Controller GameObject references in MRTK 2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I'm currently working on an application where I need to stick some objects on the user's motion controllers but I can't seem to find a way to obtain the references.

Coming from VRTK which had GameObjects exposed outside of run time, this is proving to be a bit of a challenge for me. Is there a better way of doing this on MRTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "proxy" game object for a controller, you can use the code down below (see the first part of it, which uses the visualizer's proxy game object).

It's also possible to get pointer's game object (note that a given controller may have many pointers)

If some of this terminology is confusing, I would also recommend having a read of this:
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Architecture/InputSystem/Terminology.html

Which explains some of the terms being used and how they relate to each other.

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using UnityEngine;

public class ControllerPointers : MonoBehaviour
{
   private IMixedRealityInputSystem inputSystem = null;

   /// <summary>
   /// The active instance of the input system.
   /// </summary>
   protected IMixedRealityInputSystem InputSystem
   {
       get
       {
           if (inputSystem == null)
           {
               MixedRealityServiceRegistry.TryGetService<IMixedRealityInputSystem>(out inputSystem);
           }
           return inputSystem;
       }
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
       // Log something every 60 frames.
       if (Time.frameCount % 60 == 0)
       {
           foreach (IMixedRealityController controller in InputSystem.DetectedControllers)
           {
               if (controller.Visualizer?.GameObjectProxy != null)
               {
                   Debug.Log("Visualizer Game Object: " + controller.Visualizer.GameObjectProxy);
               }
               else
               {
                   Debug.Log("Controller has no visualizer!");
               }


               foreach (IMixedRealityPointer pointer in controller.InputSource.Pointers)
               {
                   if (pointer is MonoBehaviour)
                   {
                       var monoBehavior = pointer as MonoBehaviour;
                       Debug.Log("Found pointer game object: " + (monoBehavior.gameObject));
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Lastly, you could also always grab the position/rotation/velocity properties off of the pointer interfaces themselves (i.e. in the code above, use the pointer position: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityPointer.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_Input_IMixedRealityPointer_Position)

Answer (score 0):

Check the MRTK Solvers. 
https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Solver.html

This tutorial describes in Step 4 how to "stick" a cube to the controller. (Sounds like your question)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrlearning-base-ch3

> Once you select the hand joint, you can choose which part of the hand you want >the cube to follow. For this example, we are going to use the wrist. Next to >the option Tracked Hand Joint select the dropdown menu and select Wrist.

Two things to mention... I had problems with my custom "controllers" (I have overwritten the default controller with the Oculus hands) Also check if you need the "hand joints" (like in the tutorial) or if you want to use the "motion controller left" entry in the dropdown.